# Consideration of selected lists among multiple input lists

Tags: python, list, set

Let me try to explain that confusing title to my question. I have to input 6 lists (which gets converted into sets on the go). But I want to consider only required amount of sets and assign them to set variables, say a, b, c.

Here is what I have written:

```
a,b,c = [set(raw_input().split()) for _ in range(6)][1::2]
```

The above code assigns a to 2nd list, b to 4th list and C to 6th list.

But what if I want to assign, say, a to 3rd list, b to 1st list and C to 6th list? How can I modify my code to assign such random lists to my set variables?

Hope I made my question clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small range size, such as 6, you can use underscores:

```
a, _, _, _, b, c = [set(raw_input().split()) for _ in range(6)] # Sets a to 1, b to 5, c to 6.
```

Otherwise, your slice and step will control what lists get outputted.